# Java implicit methods/parameters?

Tags: java, parameters, implicit

im currently reading a book about programming Android and there is a nice little reference guide on Java in the beginning chapters. However, I stumpled upon something about implicit parameters that I did not quite understand.

He defines the class **Car**:

```
public class Car {
  public void drive() {
    System.out.println("Going down the road!");
  }
}
```

Then he continues on with this:

```
public class JoyRide {
 private Car myCar;

 public void park(Car auto) {
   myCar = auto;
 }

 public Car whatsInTheGarage() {
   return myCar;
 }

 public void letsGo() {
   park(new Ragtop()); // Ragtop is a subclass of Car, but nevermind this.
   whatsInTheGarage().drive(); // This is the core of the question.
 }
}
```

I just want to know how we can call drive() from the class **Car** when **JoyRide** is not an extension of **Car**. Is it because the method whatsInTheGarage() is of return type **Car**, and thus it "somehow" inherits from that class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think about this piece of code:

```
whatsInTheGarage().drive();
```

as a shorthand for this:

```
Car returnedCar = whatsInTheGarage();
returnedCar.drive();
```

Is it clear now? All <del>C-like</del> languages with [c](/questions/tagged/c)-like syntax behave like this.

UPDATE:

```
myCar.drive();  //call method of myCar field

Car otherCar = new Car();
otherCar.drive();  //create new car and call its method

new Car().drive()  //call a method on just created object

public Car makeCar() {
  return new Car();
}

Car newCar = makeCar();  //create Car in a different method, return reference to it
newCar.drive();

makeCar().drive();  //similar to your case
```

Comment: I wouldn't say Java is a C-like language.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I was talking about syntax, I meant languages like C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript... - I will clarify

Comment: So you mean that; Since myCar of type Car is returned from whatsInTheGarage, we can call methods of type Car from the value returned..? But I dont understand... Neither does whatsInTheGarage return an object, nor is (in your example) returnedCar an instance of Car... It's just a variable of type Car.

Comment: @yackyackyack: I added plenty of examples to my answer, please study them all carefully. Also consider starting from a Java-only book to learn the basics. The small chapter about Java in your Android book might not be enough to learn programming basics.

Comment: I did learn the basics. I had just read the code wrong... I didn't think myCar was instantiated (overlooked park(new Ragtop())) :D. But thank you alot mate... Stupid thing to overlook, but the added examples are worth gold to me. Bookmarked!

Answer (score 4):

`whatsInTheGarage` returns a `Car`. You are invoking `drive` on the instance it returns. It's not that `JoyRide` inherits the method, `JoyRide` is invoking the method on a completely separate object.

Answer (score 3):

In the line

```
whatsInTheGarage().drive()
```

You are calling the `drive` method on the object returned from `whatsInTheGarage`.  The fact that `JoyRide` itself isn't related to `Car` is irrelevant here, because you are not trying to call `drive` on a `JoyRide` object.  Since `whatsInTheGarage` returns a `Car` and you're calling `drive` on the object returned from `whatsInTheGarage`, this will call `drive` on a `Car` object; specifically, the `Car` returned by `whatsInTheGarage`.  This doesn't have anything to do with inheritance - instead, you're just calling a method on a object that is of a class type that specifically declares that method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This made alot of sense to me, thanks bro. I realized I had overlooked that the object WAS infact instantiated in the code afterall... That's why I couldn't figure out how drive() could be called from an uninstantiated object. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, since the method returns a Car it can call the Car methods.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the class Joyride has a field of type Car. With that field, you can invoke the Car classes' methods because of this reason.